# "Giant diamond teardrops and swooping strings of chandelier glass hang imperious and heavy over the tables."

Tags: grammar, linking-verbs

(From *A Terrible Kindness* by Jo Browning Wroe)

> William takes in the ballroom's high ceiling, the pink and white embellishments, looping and twisting in and out of the alcoves. Giant diamond teardrops and swooping strings of chandelier glass **hang** **imperious** and heavy over the tables.

It seems the verb "hang" is used as a link/linking verb there and an adjective is used to complete its meaning. But then "hang" is used with adverbs as well. Is there a distinction in meaning between using the adjective and the adverb?

Comment: If **hang** is used in its intransitive sense there's probably a stylistic difference only.  Something that "hangs precariously" or that "hangs precarious" is at risk of falling in either case.

Comment: You could say ***imperious*** and ***heavy*** are "flat adverbs" rather than adjectives. But it's just a "syntactic / stylistic choice" - it makes no difference to the meaning if they *hang **imperiously** and **heavily** over the tables.*

Comment: if it helps, you can put a colon or comma after 'hang'.

Comment: On the stylistic choices, **hang imperious and heavy** sounds fine to me but I don't think all adjectives could be  substituted equally well for their adverb counterparts.  **hang menacing** sounds a little off to my ear. And it is likely to have to do with the duo of adjectives, since **hang menacing and ominous** sounds a lot better than **menacing** alone.

Comment: It's equivalent to “teardrops and strings, heavy and imperious, hang”.